Show that a submodule of $R((X))$ is finitely generated
$R$ is a Noetherian commutative ring. And $R((X))$ is the ring of Laurent series in $X$ over $R$, its elements are the sequences $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ of elements of $R$
indexed by $\mathbb Z$ for which there exists an integer $n_0 \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a_n = 0$ for each $n < n_0$. The multiplication in this ring is given by
$$f= (a_n),\ g= (b_n),\quad fg= (c_n)\ ,\ c_n= \sum_{i\in \mathbb Z} a_ib_{n-i}$$
The ring of formal power series $R[[X]] := \{\sum_{n\geq0} a_nX^n, a_n \in R \text{ for each } n \geq 0 \}$ is a subring of $R((X))$. 
So, $R((X))$ can be viewed as an $R[[X]]$-module.
For each non-zero $f= (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z} \in R((X))$, we define the order of $f$, denoted $ord(f)$, to be the smallest integer $n$ such that $a_n \neq 0$, define the leading coefficient of $f$, denoted $lc(f)$, to be $a_n$. For $f = 0$, set $ord(f) = \infty$ and $lc(f) = 0$ .
Let $N$ be a non-zero $R[[X]]$-submodule of $R((X))$. Suppose that each element of $N$ has order at least $d$ for some fixed integer $d$.
We choose a non-zero $f_1$ in $N$ of smallest order $d_1$ and we set $a_1 = lc(f_1)$.
If there is an element $f_2$ of $N$ with $lc(f_2) \notin Ra_1$, we choose one of smallest order $d_2$ and set $a_2 = lc(f_2)$. If there is an element $f_3$ of $N$ with $lc(f_3) \notin Ra_1 + Ra_2$, we choose one of smallest order $d_3$ and we set $a_3 = lc(f_3)$, etc. This sequence eventually terminates with some $f_k$ of order $d_k$ with $a_k = lc(f_k)$ such that $lc(f) \in Ra_1+\dots +Ra_k$ for any $f \in N$.
We want to prove that $N$ is generated by $f_1, \dots , f_k$ as an $R[[X]]$-module, any hints on how to proceed?

Maybe some idea is: Let $N_{i} \subseteq R$ be the set of elements $r \in R$ such that there exists $f \in N$ such that $\mathrm{coef}(X^{i},f) = r$. Then each $N_{i}$ is an ideal of $R$ and we have an ascending chain \begin{align} \dotsb \subseteq N_{i-1} \subseteq N_{i} \subseteq N_{i+1} \subseteq \dotsb \end{align} (which must stabilize since $R$ is Noetherian), and moreover $N_{i} = 0$ for all $i < d$.
